# how do we style php array using css?

Tags: php, css, visual-studio-2010

** $errors array is the erros that will give when the user enters invalid form data, so
i wish to style the $errors array below? how can i do that ? like i want to colour it and do some styling **

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $errors = array(); // create an errors array to record errors if any.
        // check if the name is provided and is valid
        if(empty($_POST['Make1'])) {
        $errors[] = 'Make 1 is required.'; // if name is required
        } else {
        $Make1 = trim($_POST['Make1']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Make1)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid Make1! use only letters and white space.";
        }}
        if (empty($_POST['Make2'])) {
            $errors[] = 'Make 2 is required.';
            } else {
            $Make2 = trim($_POST['Make2']);
              if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$Make2)) {
            $errors[] = "Invalid Make 2! use only letters and white space.";
    }}
```

Comment: Wrap each error into a div.error `echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(fn($e) => "<div class=error>{$e}</div>", $errors));`

Comment: is there any easier way?

Comment: What is complicated on that? You could write it as an foreach loop which does the same.

Comment: i didnt uunderstand this bit "echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(fn($e) =>"

Comment: $error is an array. Array_map iterates over it and returns for each error a div. Implode joins that returned new array with a PHP_EOL for each entry. Why don't you test and debug that?

Comment: so where do i put this line "echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(fn($e) => "<div class=error>{$e}</div>", $errors));"

Comment: At the end of your code?!

Comment: can you tell me step by step what to do ?

Comment: Just place the code at the end of your code. You should make yourself familiar with basic coding before you ask for code solutions. The code is easy, I've explained in detail and you can read the PHP reference.

Comment: but the webpage is not running when i put this code in

Comment: Are you below PHP 7.4? Then you can not use closure shorthands. Instead use `echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(function($e) { return "<div class=error>{$e}</div>"; }, $errors));`

Comment: so the code is giving no error but now how do i style the errors?

Comment: Use CSS to style a div with class error. You also should learn the very basics about HTML and CSS when using PHP to create or handle web content. Thanks to Tangentially Perpendicular for the well written summary as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your `$errors` array and wrap each message in a `<div>` that you can style with CSS. (Code thanks to Markus Zeller in the comments)

```
echo implode(PHP_EOL, 
         array_map(
           function($e) { return "<div class=error>{$e}</div>"; }, 
           $errors
         )
     );
```

In this snippet `array_map()` iterates over the `$errors` array and returns an array with each element updated by the callback function.
The callback function wraps each message from the array in a `<div>`, including a CSS class for styling.
Finally, the newly created array is `imploded` to give a single string to `echo`.

Input:

```
$errors = ["Error message 1", "Error Message 2"];
```

Output:

```
<div class=error>Error message 1</div>
<div class=error>Error message 2</div>
```

Now style it by adding some CSS:

```
.error {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:pink;
}
```

Comment: ok so its working now but i have like so many errors to display so do i have to write this code so many times or is there an easier way that i can call the function or something?

Comment: This is a one-time piece of code that you run after you've found all your errors. There are other ways you might do this, including using HTML attributes on your `<input>` elements and the browser handles it all. You clearly don't understand what you're doing, and [so] is not the place for tutorials. Work through the one line of code we've provided and understand it. Then ask questions.